# Filtering PlacePicker results by placeIDs in Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I have collection of placeIDs, I want the place picker to show only those places as a result. Is there any way to get filtration by placeIDS ?

```
  PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your custom location on place picker  Call setLatLngBounds() on the builder.